# Visiting UK with family for tourism - I already have Business Visitor Visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, tourist-visas

I have been issued a UK Business visit visa in the past and have been to UK without my family once, after that I applied again for a new Visa and got 6 Months Multiple Entry visa, I was supposed to travel to UK on Feb 7, 2019 but due to upcoming meetings at my office I will not be able to travel on the said date.

I have my leave approved for one week in April, and this time I will be going for tourism only and my wife and my kids (3 years and 1.5 years) want to travel with me for tourism as my wife was pretty jealous seeing my last visit pics :P

I already have the visa so I believe my wife needs to apply for a visa along with the kids. I was just curious what should I write in the cover letter. I will arrange hotel bookings and itinerary which will include what we will be doing in UK in 7 days visit (places we will visit).

Do I need to write separate cover letters for my childern as I believe I have to submit their applications separately, and what document should I attach with their applications.

Anyone who has done similar process can explain so I do not get the rejection for my family as my wife is really excited to visit UK, that will be her first visit outside of Pakistan.

Just quick details My wife is highly educated but she is not doing any job, she has around 1 Million in savings account (no big transactions in last 6 months just 20,000 coming per month as her pocket money).

Comment: This will answer your question. Note that in your case, your wife is now the **primary applicant**. Your visa has already been issued so you are no longer an applicant. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107336/how-to-apply-for-a-uk-standard-visitor-visa-as-a-family?rq=1

Comment: Write one cover letter for them and attach a copy of your visa and bank statements explaining you’re her husband and financing the trip.

Comment: @SyedZ Did your employer sponsor your visa (eg were they paying travel costs)? If the premise of your original trip was solely business, you might want to check with the issuing embassy that your visa remains valid, especially as you are now planning to travel with your family (having them stay behind in Pakistan would have demonstrated a strong reason to return in your original application, which will not be the case now that the purpose of your trip has changed).

Comment: @Traveller nope this visa isn't related to employer it was a professional gathering I was going to I just submitted the leave letter from employer a kind of NOC that he has no issue with me to attend this conference/gathering. I have pretty solid bank statement (salaried + saving) and both time I mentioned that I will fund my own trip.

Comment: @Syedz In that case, see V9.3 regarding change of purpose https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Comment: @Traveller change of purpose implies a purpose that is not within the scope of the visa already issued. Since the standard visitor visa allows business AND tourism the OP would jot be affected--especially if he already let's the UKVI know through his family's applications.

Comment: I did some research and I would add this to my cover letter that I am going on some business meetings (which I actually does have) and I want to take my family as meeting is for one day and I have 6 days for family time in London I will show proper travel arrangements and hotel bookings I think this should satisfy the ECO. What is your expert opinion on this?