# Marriage and birth certificates for a family tourist visa to the UK

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am applying for me, my wife, and daughter for a trip to the UK for tourism. I will be the one finanically responsible for the family for the whole trip. I will provide my bank statement with my application

Do I also need to provide a marriage certificate and a birth certificate for my daughter ?

If yes, when uploading the documents for each application to the Visa Application Center (VAC). Do I upload the marriage certificate, for example, twice ? for me and my wife ?.

Do I also upload the bank statement for each application ? Or just for my application with a letter mentioning who I will be providing to ?

Thank you

Comment: Your wife will need to submit her **own** bank statement in addition to yours

Comment: @NicolasFormichella but her bank balance does not cover the cost, and I will be the one responsible for the family. Isn't there a way to link my bank statement to all ?

Comment: **No**, all applicants must follow the document requirements, which include bank statements. Even if your only bank account to both of you is a joint account

Comment: Do you think that not having enough in her bank statement might get the application refused ? (Even if I have more than enough for the entire family)

Comment: I am actually wrong in the above statement, I am sorry. Please see this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/107359/118049) from a late eminent community member and UK Solicitor